# I am learning English because I will need it when I go abroad

Tags: differences, modal-verbs, future, subordinate-clauses

Which ones of the following could be correct:

> I am learning English because I will need it when I go abroad.
>
> I am learning English because I need it when I go abroad.

What I imply is that I am not abroad now but I am likely to go abroad in the future.

If both are correct, is there any difference in terms of meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both correct.  It depends on what you want to say.

**I am about to go to a place where I will be expected to speak English. So,...**

*I am learning English because I will need it when I go abroad.*

**I go abroad to work often.  My English is passable but could be better.  So, ...**

*I am learning English because I need it when I go abroad.*

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly noticed it (your being abroad) will happen in the `future`, that means that you should put the verb - `need` - in the future tense, i.e.

> I am learning English because I will need it when I go abroad.

The second sentence can be fixed like this:

> I am learning English because I need it at work.

But you cannot do something in the present (I need) and in the future (when I go abroad) simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When we say "I am learning English because I need it at work." Can I suppose I already a job which requires English skills or I own an company that I did not use to work  with other companies which are from abroad but I just started.So I need it now.

Comment: I think if somebody does not a job now  but a job they are looking for is likely to require English skill, for example travel agent,I would say " I am learning English because I will need it at work."

Comment: Correct, if you need it for any reason in the future, you should say `I will need it`.

You might want to start with some more basic English teaching websites before posting questions here, that will save you much time.

Comment: You could say, though, "I am learning English because I need it for going/traveling abroad."

Comment: "I will need it" and "when I go abroad" are both referring to the future.